# Undo changes made in an xml file using vi editor

Tags: xml, ubuntu, vi, undo

I made changes in a .xml file using vi editor in ubuntu terminal and saved the file with changes (used :wq). Is there any way I can undo the changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little hope. VI creates a swap file that is deleted when you quit VI. Depending on your file system you may be able to undelete this swap file. If VI then finds the swap file it should give you an opportunity to recover.